# Programming_question on dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

A company produces a product. The production is done in a very mysterious way. The firm either produces one extra product in a day or they have a power to double the production of products they had on the previous day. Initially they have only 1 product and after some day they have exactly "n" products. You need to find out the minimum days in order to make exactly "n" products.
TESTCASE:
n = 8
output = 3
explanation: If production is doubled every day, than in three days it is possible to make 1 x 2 x 2 x 2 = 8 products.
Few more:
For 15 products OUTPUT 6
For 19 products OUTPUT 6

Comment: So is this a programming contest question with a prize? :)

Comment: What have you tried, and how did your attempts fail? What research have you done on the problem? You've tagged both [tag:dynamic-programming] and [tag:greedy]. Do you think either one of those approaches will work? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve this using dynamic programming. For a given `n` products, start populating from the bottom up manner. Please find the code below with your test cases passing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{

   int n = -1, i =0, tmp=0;
   // int result = -1;
   printf("\nEnter value: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   if (n == -1)
    return -1;


   if(n == 1)
   {
    printf("\nOnly a single day");
    return 0;
   }


   int *arr = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

   for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    arr[i]=INT_MAX;


   arr[0] = 1;

   for(i=1; i<n; i++)
   {
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + 1;

    if ((i+1)%2 == 0)
    {
        tmp = arr[(i+1)/2 - 1] + 1;
        if (tmp < arr[i])
            arr[i] = tmp;
    }

   }

   printf("\nResult: %d", arr[n-1]-1);
}
```

Output:

**Test Case 1:**

```
Enter value: 8

Result: 3
```

**Test Case 2:**

```
Enter value: 15

Result: 6
```

**Test Case 3:**

```
Enter value: 19

Result: 6
```

**CODE EXPLANATION:**

You need to construct an array containing as much number of elements as is the value. For eg. if the value is 8, you need to construct the array having 8 elements. Then you need deal with value 2,3,4 .... till 8. There is no need for value 1 since when you start, the problem states you already have `1` with you. The value in the array elements signify the number of days. The array index is such that `index = value -1`.

Your final aim is to get to `8`. But you need to start from bottom up. You need to ask yourself what best you can do (minimum number of days) with value `2`? It is either the previous element's value +1 (since the problem states you either do `day's value = previous day's value + 1`) or the best that you were doing with value half of the current value plus `1` (the problem states that you can multiply by 2 also the other day). Whichever number is less you assign it to the current value's index. This logic is inside the `for` loop for each index.

You repeat the steps for 3,4,.... till 8. Now when you reach `8`, the value at the index (`8-1`) contain days including the start, therefore you need to subtract 1 and finally display the value.

Comment: What does this code actually do? Code-only answers are significantly less helpful than commented code with a description of the algorithm used.

Comment: Yes I realised it later, I have added the code explanation in my answer. Maybe it will serve the purpose well. Thank You.

Comment: This feels overly cumbersome compared to position of most significant bit set (where the least significant bit is considered position 0) + number of bits set - 1.